# VBA way to manually save the excel file based on 'dynamic' parameters passed.

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an application using excel macro, where the user feeds certain values and saves it to several directory path with a button click macro.

When I select a region from drop down, it should save the file to designated region folder. Say for eg, when NY is selected, the file will be saved to shared drive and 2016 - NY folder. But now, deciding the future of the application, I am thinking of having "year" as a separate field in the worksheet, which retrieves the year value from the user. How do I achieve this without the necessity to change the code every year. The process will be continuing  for 'n' number of years from now. Thanks in Advance !

```
FileName1 = Range("D3").Value
filenameOfNewBook = FileName1


If location = "Illinois" Then

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\Illinois\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

ElseIf location = "LA" Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\LA\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

ElseIf location = "NY" Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\NY\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

Else
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\Atlanta\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

 End If

 MsgBox "File Saved successfully!", , "Save"
 ActiveWorkbook.save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: `FileName:="W:\Audits\" & Year(Date) & "\" & location  & "\"`?

Comment: Where is the rest of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience for office tasks purpose, it's better not to refer to current year, but year set by user, so for example in January 2017 user can still perform actions on files related to 2016. You can get rid of the following:

```
If location = "Illinois" Then

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\Illinois\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

ElseIf location = "LA" Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\LA\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

ElseIf location = "NY" Then
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\NY\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

Else
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\2016\Atlanta\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"

End If
```

And instead use:

```
Dim myYear as String, locations() as String, locationForPath as String
Dim locCounter as Long

myYear = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").value2 'the cell with year value, for example 2016  

locations = Split("Illinois,LA,NY",",")

For locCounter = LBound(locations) to UBound(locations)
   If location = locations(locCounter) Then locationForPath = location: Exit For
Next locCounter

If locationForPath = vbNullString Then locationForPath = "Atlanta"

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="W:\Audits\" & myYear & "\" & locationForPath & "\" & FileName1 & "-" & "checklist" & ".xlsm"
```

Comment: Hi. But this doesn't eventually direct the files to the respective destination year folders right? I am trying to point the  files to different folders based on year and destination. Say for eg., I have individual folders for 2016, 2017, 2018 and so on. Each of these folders, has individual locations. so I am thinking of sorting the files to their folders, rather than having one folder with all files

Comment: The logic behind my macro is exactly the same as logic in your code: multiple location folders in one year folder. You can always consider reading more years from spreadsheet, which refer to let's say every file name and looping through them.